# Проверить наличие игры

Tags: php, steam-web-api

Делаю запрос `http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=****key****&steamid=76561198136664210&format=json` делаю `json_decode()` и получаю

```
Array
(
    [response] => Array
        (
            [game_count] => 42
            [games] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 70110
                            [playtime_forever] => 124
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 70000
                            [playtime_forever] => 519
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 105600
                            [playtime_forever] => 369
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 204340
                            [playtime_2weeks] => 260
                            [playtime_forever] => 4528
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 204360
                            [playtime_forever] => 189
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 1930
                            [playtime_forever] => 439
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 232770
                            [playtime_forever] => 96
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 239450
                            [playtime_forever] => 55
                        )

                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 243780
                            [playtime_forever] => 382
                        )

                    [9] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 251690
                            [playtime_forever] => 518
                        )

                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 253900
                            [playtime_forever] => 277
                        )

                    [11] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 253980
                            [playtime_forever] => 393
                        )

                    [12] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 254000
                            [playtime_forever] => 0
                        )

                    [13] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 254020
                            [playtime_forever] => 0
                        )

                    [14] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 254040
                            [playtime_forever] => 0
                        )

                    [15] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 254060
                            [playtime_forever] => 0
                        )

                    [16] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 259280
                            [playtime_forever] => 0
                        )

                    [17] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 275490
                            [playtime_forever] => 638
                        )

                    [18] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 278460
                            [playtime_forever] => 122
                        )

                    [19] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 283370
                            [playtime_forever] => 0
                        )

                    [20] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 286360
                            [playtime_forever] => 0
                        )

                    [21] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 287100
                            [playtime_forever] => 0
                        )

                    [22] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 292380
                            [playtime_forever] => 467
                        )

                    [23] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 292390
                            [playtime_forever] => 0
                        )

                    [24] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 295930
                            [playtime_forever] => 479
                        )

                    [25] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 41050
                            [playtime_forever] => 0
                        )

                    [26] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 41060
                            [playtime_forever] => 0
                        )

                    [27] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 227780
                            [playtime_forever] => 211
                        )

                    [28] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 299260
                            [playtime_forever] => 0
                        )

                    [29] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 8980
                            [playtime_forever] => 0
                        )

                    [30] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 301700
                            [playtime_forever] => 0
                        )

                    [31] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 301750
                            [playtime_forever] => 155
                        )

                    [32] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 303390
                            [playtime_forever] => 72
                        )

                    [33] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 304050
                            [playtime_forever] => 0
                        )

                    [34] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 304930
                            [playtime_forever] => 245
                        )

                    [35] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 227940
                            [playtime_2weeks] => 31
                            [playtime_forever] => 31
                        )

                    [36] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 10
                            [playtime_forever] => 98
                        )

                    [37] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 80
                            [playtime_forever] => 0
                        )

                    [38] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 100
                            [playtime_forever] => 0
                        )

                    [39] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 240
                            [playtime_forever] => 0
                        )

                    [40] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 730
                            [playtime_2weeks] => 2269
                            [playtime_forever] => 58557
                        )

                    [41] => Array
                        (
                            [appid] => 410210
                            [playtime_forever] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Нужно узнать есть ли тут игра с `appid = 730`, одним словом проверить наличие CS:GO, есть идея перебирать в цикле но хотелось бы знать есть ли вариант лучше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **appids_filter**
>   You can optionally filter the list to a set of appids. Note that these cannot be passed as a URL parameter, instead you must use the JSON format described in Steam_Web_API#Calling_Service_interfaces. The expected input is an array of integers (in JSON: "appids_filter: [ 440, 500, 550 ]" )

Answer (score 0):

Запрос по конкретной игре можно сделать в подобном формате:

`http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=***&steamid=***&format=json&include_played_free_games=1&appids_filter[0]=730&include_appinfo=1` ,где в ключе **&appids_filter[0]=730** значение 730 является ID игры.

В ответе будет присутствовать одна из строк **"game_count": 1** или **"game_count": 0**, которая указывает на присутствие игры на аккаунте.

з.ы. сам "game_count" возвращает количество игр, что в принципе и говориться в названии этого ключа.

Comment: Не могли бы вы коротко пояснить предложенное решение.

Comment: так же можно перечислить несколько игр **&appids_filter[0]=730&appids_filter[1]=10**, где "game_count" будет указывать на количество игр подходящий под запрос